# Can I output custom or specific data (Not related to an elementType) on Element API?

Tags: plugin-elementapi

For example, an endpoint to retrieve all the languages available on the website

```
'endpoints' => [   
   'languages' => function () {

            $sites = Craft::$app->getSites()->getAllGroups();

            $languages = Craft::$app->getSites()->getSitesByGroupId($sites[array_search('Languages', $sites)]['id']);

            Craft::dd($languages); // output this in a nice json

            return $languages;
        },
    ]
```

Or an endpoint to retrieve all the available sections

```
    'sections' => function () {

            $sections = Craft::$app->getSections()->getAllSections();

            Craft::dd($sections); // output this in a nice json
    },
```

Comment: I can't think of a clean way to do this, it would be easier to create a custom controller for it

Comment: You're right, I've made a custom module for it and it was super simple. I think I'll use this in combination with Element API.

Comment: Would you mind adding your solution as an official answer in case it helps someone in the future, @JorgeAnzola?

Comment: Yes! I will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed as [@robin](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/users/5557/robin-schambach) pointed out, I couldn't figure out a nice way to making custom data outputs with Element API (Not related to a ElementType, like available Sites/Languages or available sections). What I did was:

I created a [custom module](https://nystudio107.com/blog/enhancing-a-craft-cms-3-website-with-a-custom-module), in this module I was able to register routes like:

```
        Event::on(
            UrlManager::class,
            UrlManager::EVENT_REGISTER_SITE_URL_RULES,
            function (RegisterUrlRulesEvent $event) {

                $event->rules['api/languages'] = '/endpoints/endpoints/languages';
            }
        );
```

And in the action of the module. (Still is a rough version, also needs to handle possible errors and that kind of stuff)

```
public function actionLanguages()
{
    $sites = Craft::$app->getSites()->getAllGroups();

    $languages = Craft::$app->getSites()->getSitesByGroupId($sites[array_search('Languages', $sites)]['id']);

    return $this->asJson($this->formatApiResponse($languages));
}
```

I don't know if it's the nicest way (Still open to suggestions) but this gave me the freedom I needed to enhance my Element API end-points.